# Increasing Youtube API v3 Quota without business information

Tags: youtube-api

Youtube API v3 currently allows 10,000 units per day and uploading a video costs roughly 1600 units.

With the cost of an upload being so expensive I blow my quota well before the end of the day where as if i use youtube.com/upload I can upload 100+ videos a day if i wanted to.

I've tried looking for contact methods for billing, checking the request quota increase form (requires business info).

I need a way to increase the daily units since the current daily unit restriction is way too strict compared to their main websites limits.

Comment: I think the only way you can request the increase is via [Quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/quotas) tab in the Developer's Console.

Comment: Yeah, that required business information.

Was hoping there would be an alternative way to increase the quota D: